# How to allow newly created role to login into wordpress admin?

Tags: php, wordpress

> I have created new role in wordpress, I want that user with this role can login into wordpress admin.

```
            $result = add_role( 'sub_admin', __(

            'Sub Admin' ),

            array(
                'read' => true, // true allows this capability
                'edit_posts' => true, // Allows user to edit their own posts
                'create_posts' => true, // Allows user to create new posts
                'publish_posts' => true, // Allows the user to publish, otherwise posts stays in draft mode
                'install_plugins' => false, // User cant add new plugins
                'update_plugin' => false, // User can’t update any plugins
                'update_core' => false // user cant perform core updates
            )

        );
```

This is the code i added to add new role..Can any one suggest me the solution?

Answer (score 0):

`read` allows access to administration panel. You already have it. You can find more about capabilities and which roles they're assigned to by default [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities)

Comment: It shows me this , 
You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.

When i tried to login with the user having "sub_admin" role.

Comment: Which page are you trying to access in wp-admin?

Answer (score 0):

While creating new role, make sure that appropriate capabilities are assigned to that role. For example, following code will add three permissions

1. `"read"` 
   Allows access to Administration Panel options:
   i.e. Dashboard and Users > Your Profile
2. `"edit_posts"`
   Allows to edit posts
3. `"delete_posts"`
   Allows to delete posts

So user added to this role will have all these capabilities inherited from this role.

```
$result = add_role(
    'basic_contributor',
    __( 'Basic Contributor' ),
    array(
        'read'         => true,  // true allows this capability
        'edit_posts'   => true,
        'delete_posts' => false, // Use false to explicitly deny
    )
);
if ( null !== $result ) {
    echo 'Yay! New role created!';
}
else {
    echo 'Oh... the basic_contributor role already exists.';
}
```

Comment: Role is created successfully. And i can see it in admin, And also create users in it.. But I am not able to login to word press admin area using these role...

for example, I created test user with role sub_admin.. But i am not able to login into admin..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/capability-manager-enhanced/screenshots/

It will provide you all the functionalities like

- Create a new role
- Update user role's capabilities

> ***Steps to do this :***

- Install and activate plugin
- There will be new menu ***capabilities*** under users menu
- In there, there will be option to create role in right sidebar
- There will be one option ***Select Role to View / Edit*** to modify capability of specific role
- And now you have to assign that role to desired user

***Moreover,*** You can view the capabilities of admin and author user role to understand which capabilities will be required to allow user to access specific area.

That's all

WordPress is all about ***plugins***. So, it would be easy if you find any plugin for your requirements. It will save your all the time and it will do all the coding for you.

Comment: @HasmukhMistry haha... np...I was asking to whoever did it... accept my answer if you find it useful.

Comment: I already gone through the plugin, It did not solved my problem .. Can you try it?

Comment: @HasmukhMistry I've provided step by step guide. Pl. check.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = add_role('sub_admin', __('Sub Admin' ),array());

// gets the sub admin role
$sub_admin = get_role( 'sub_admin' );

//lets assign contributor other roles
$sub_admin->add_cap( 'read' );

$sub_admin->add_cap( 'edit_posts' );
$sub_admin->add_cap( 'create_posts' );
$sub_admin->add_cap( 'publish_posts' );
```

> This worked , Nicely ... It solved my problem.